# Let $X$ be a random variable following the standard cauchy distribution. Show that $E[X^{\alpha}]$ exists, $\forall\alpha\in(0,1)$

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a random variable following the standard cauchy
> distribution. Show that $E[X^{\alpha}]$ exists,
> $\forall\alpha\in(0,1)$

According to me, $E[X^{0.5}]=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+1}dx$ can not exist because, how can you integrate an expression involving $\sqrt{x}$ over $(-\infty,0)$.

so, obviously the above statement is wrong. But it is given that the above statement is correct! where am i going wrong?

Comment: $X^{\alpha}$ is not defined as a real number when $X <0$. The correct statement is $E|X|^{\alpha} <\infty$ for $0 <\alpha <1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X^{\alpha} $ is not a well-defined random variable so the statement is clearly false.

The correct statement is $E|X|^{\alpha} <\infty$ for $0 <\alpha <1$.

$\frac {|x|^{\alpha}} {1+x^{2}} \leq \min \,\, ({1, \frac 1 {|x|^{2-\alpha}}})$ and you can check that $\min \,\, ({1, \frac 1 {|x|^{2-\alpha}}})$ is integrable by splitting the integral into integral over $|x| \leq 1$ and integral over $|x|>1$.

Comment: Is $X^{\alpha}, \alpha\in(0,1)$ not a well-defined random variable over the field of complex numbers also?

Comment: It does not have a unique value even when you use complex numbers. @abhishek